# dpkg: error porccessing archive (--unpack)

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux

[image][image][image]I got this error message when trying to run `sudo apt -f install`.

```
dpkg: error proccessing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes_2020.3.2_all.deb(--unpack)
errors were encountered while proccessing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kali-defaults_2020.3.4_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/kali-themes_2020.3.2_all.deb
sub-proccess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in a kali package.    What happens if you `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-theme_2020.3.2_all.deb` or `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-defaults_2020.3.2_all.deb`?  I'm curious which package has the bug.

Comment: i wrote this in terminal sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-theme_2020.3.2_all.deb    dpkg : error: cannot access archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kali-theme_2020.3.2_all.deb  : no such file or directory. I added this photo

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text); instead, copy-and-paste it into your question using proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite kali-themes tilix-common libgtkd-3-0 libphobos2-ldc-shared91 libvted-3-0
sudo apt -f install  
sudo apt install tilix
```